# NGINX displaying default page, domain's not redirecting

Tags: networking, ubuntu, proxy, webserver, nginx

I am currently trying to deploy my Django app on an Ubuntu 18.04.3 droplet. I am following along with this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I have successfully completed the tutorial, and my app is served when visiting my server's IP and "www.domainname.com". However, when I try to visit my domain's address without the "www" @ 'domainname.com' it shows

> refused to connect.

And as I stated before, when I go to directly to the IP address it displays 100% correctly and serves the app's static files.

I'm assuming it has something to do with NGINX configuration because I completed every other part of the tutorial correctly with no errors.

Here is my NGINX server block @ `/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 165.227.222.0;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ethan/cfsite/cfsite;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I commented out the default server block completely in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` as I read it is symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.

When I `sudo tail -F /var/log/nginx/error.log` I get this:

```
2019/09/26 14:25:58 [alert] 6680#6680: *3 open socket #3 left in connection 4
2019/09/26 14:25:58 [alert] 6680#6680: aborting
```

I am assuming there is some issue with a proxy somewhere or the registrar is not correctly redirecting to DigitalOcean being that accessing the DO IP directly yields the correct results with static files served.

Please help! It's a simple portfolio website, and I've never configured a server before.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points:

- [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) should typically include all the names you want to use for that server e.g.:

  ```
  server_name example.com www.example.com 165.227.222.0;
  ```
- Any DNS records for your domain should have a "bare" or "naked" A Record pointing at the IP of your Nginx server:

  *ex. BIND*

  ```
  example.com.    IN A    165.227.222.0    ; A Record for a "base" domain name
  ```

  If you are using a third-party for DNS, how you specify this "bare" record may vary. For Digital Ocean DNS services, this appears to be with the `@` symbol.

  *ex. Digital Ocean "Bare" A Record*

  [image: Digital Ocean "Bare" A Record - Screenshot]

Comment: thank you for those tips. I have added all 3 server_name's to my Nginx server block, and my DigitalOcean project now has 5 DNS records: 2 A records pointing "www.domainname.com" and "domainname.com" to my server's IP address, and 3 NameServer records pointing my domain to DigitalOcean's nameservers (1, 2, and 3). My domain's registrar is also pointing my domain name to all 3 DO nameservers. Now, however, my website only displays on the server's IP address, and not at all on "www.domainname.com" or "domainname.com"